# Issue in reading and seting headers in cordova using cordovaHTTP plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cookies

I'm using [cordovaHTTP](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP) plugin as mentioned in docs, the plugin only returns response body, and also cookies set by a response won't be sent in future request (only in Android).

My questions are:

1. Why this library can't return headers? knowing that it uses a [Java library](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) which is able to return headers.
2. Is the aforementioned Cookie limitation because of a limitation in Phonegap or it's just based on the implementation of the plugin itself.
   (I'm trying to know if it's solvable or not).
3. If the Cookies limitation stems from Phonegap structure, The question is Why? Cause I can not find a derefence between Native web view and default browser in Docs showing this limitation.